# Changing a object field in a matrix at a position changes other objects field at other locations in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose that the class has 2 or 3 fields. I create a matrix of that class objects. If I change the field of the object at a particular position in the matrix then fields are affected at other positions in the matrix to

**Class and matrix declaration**

```py
class Edge:
     def __init__(self,isCool=False,num=1):
             self.isCool = isCool
             self.num = num

Ed = Edge()
edgeMatrix = [[Ed for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

**Right now the output I gets**

```py
>>> edgeMatrix[0][2].isCool
False
>>> edgeMatrix[2][2].isCool
False
```

**If I change the field of the object at a particular location**

```
edgeMatrix[0][2].isCool = True
```

**Then why is the edgeMatrix at [2][2] changing**

```py
>>> edgeMatrix[0][2].isCool
True
>>> edgeMatrix[2][2].isCool
True
```

*I can obviously create a new Edge object with isCool = True and store it at that location but why am I getting this problem in the above case*

Comment: It's the same object in the whole matrix. You need to create a new Edge in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same object at all matrix positions.

```
Ed = Edge() # construct an Edge object
edgeMatrix = [[Ed for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)] # Put Ed everywhere
```

`Ed` is an object with an fixed address. What you do in your list comprehension is just put the reference for this object in all your matrix positions.

If you want distinct `Edge` objects you have to construct them:

```
edgeMatrix = [[Edge() for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)] # Create a new Edge for all the indices.
```